# How to restrict excel from closing while remotely entering data

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that prevent the excel from closing while I fill in number remotely to a column. Initially I already ask the user to enter the ID. the next step is prevent closing . How can it be done?

below is the code for ID enter and cell selection.

```
Sub Enter_1()
Dim data_1 As String
Dim sCell As Variant
Dim rslt As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Do
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    data_1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Employee No.", Title:="Employee", Default:="Enter Employee No. here")

    If data_1 = "" Then
        QuestionToMessageBox = "Exit?"
        YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "No")
    End If

    If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbNo Then

        data_1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Employee No.", Title:="Employee", Default:="Enter Employee No. here")

    Exit sub    
    End If

        If Not IsNumeric(data_1) Or data_1 = "" Then
            rslt = 0
        Else: rslt = 1
        End If

        If rslt = 0 Then
         MsgBox "You can only enter a number in this field"

        Else:
            Sheets("Oven After Assay Test").Activate
            For x = 6 To 50
                If Cells(x, 8).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(x, 8).Select
                    cancel = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Loop While rslt = 0



End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to use the Before_close workbook event. Just set the Cancel property to true to stop if from closing. But if a user wants to kill Excel, you can't really stop them. [google](http://google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the requested functionality as follows:

Insert the code Module and add the following line:

```
 Public FlagToClose As Boolean
```

In `ThisWorkbook` VBA code module add `Sub`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    FlagToClose = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not FlagToClose Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Modify your procedure as followoing:

```
Sub Enter_1()
    FlagToClose = False

    'YOUR PROCEDURE
    '.....................

    FlagToClose = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks it works. The next thing is initially I have the input from the data_1. To unlock the "not to close" function I need to key in the same input (data_2) by creating a inputbox at different sub. if both the value data_1 and data_2 match, then it will unlock. How to link the two input from sub1 to sub2?  any idea to do it in the same sub Enter_1()

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it works for you, so the question is considered answered. To avoid this comments thread becoming a sort of "Russian Doll Question", please post your additional questions separately. Good luck with your project. Best regards,